# TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk with WebSocket's

Tags: javascript, websocket, typeerror

I've been getting a lot of TypeError's recently with [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and Node.JS recently. What I'm trying to do is broadcast message's to all users using a simple for loop. The array I'm sending is a UInt8Array() if it helps. Here's the function:

```
function broadcast(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
        if(clients[i]){
            clients[i].send(data, {binary:true});
        }
    }
}
```

The call:

```
broadcast(messages.movement.build(conn.id, conn.snake.direction.x, conn.snake.direction.y));

broadcast(messages.direction.build(conn.id, conn.snake.direction));
```

messages/movement:

```
var message = require('../utils/message');

var type = 'G'.charCodeAt(0);

exports.build = function(id, x, y) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(9);
    var b = 0;
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, 0);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, 0);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, type);
    b += message.writeInt16(b, arr, id);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, x);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, y);
    return arr;
};
```

messages/direction:

```
var message = require('../utils/message');

var type = 'e'.charCodeAt(0);

exports.build = function(id, direction) {
    var arr = new Uint8Array(7);
    var b = 0;
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, 0);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, 0);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, type);
    b += message.writeInt16(b, arr, id);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, direction.angle);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, 104);
    b += message.writeInt8(b, arr, 0);
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: Can someone please help? I've been getting this error for a while and I can't find a fix!